# Chromium Branding in MacOS

Tags: c++, google-chrome, chromium, gn

I have been trying to change the branding of Chromium in MacOS. I have tried editing theses file:

- `src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/BRANDING`
- `chrome/app/general_resources.grd`
- `chrome/app/settings_strings.grdp`
- `chrome/app/chromium_strings.grd`
- `chtome/common/chrome_paths_mac.mm`
- `chtome/common/chrome_constants.cc`

After trying all the permutations and combinations of making changes in the above files, whenever I try building from source, the directories that are created are all named `@PRODUCT_FULLNAME@` (eg: `@PRODUCT_FULLNAME@ Framework.framework`, `@PRODUCT_FULLNAME@ Helper`, etc.).

I tried launching the file
`out/MyBuild/@PRODUCT_FULLNAME@.app/Contents/MacOS/@PRODUCT_FULLNAME@`, but it crashed and threw an error. After some research, I came to know that the full name is set in the file `build/util/branding.gni`. I tried changing the full name from that file directly and it worked, the directories were titled with the name given by me instead of `@PRODUCT_FULLNAME@`. Yet, when I tried launching the browser, it crashed again.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here, I tried referring to the below questions:

- [Change Chromium Branding (MacOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043303/change-chromium-branding-macos)
- ["icudtl.dat not found in bundle" when launching custom branded Chromium build on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959186/icudtl-dat-not-found-in-bundle-when-launching-custom-branded-chromium-build-on) (I tried making changes in the file mentioned in this link, but it still ends up as `@PRODUCT_FULLNAME@`)
- [Chromium - mini_installer ignores branding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307180/chromium-mini-installer-ignores-branding/50308199#50308199).

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution,You can check my:

chromium version 98.0.4758.0,i build it on windows and mac all good.

### All files:

```
build/win/reorder-imports.py line 28,28,77,85,87 

chrome/build.gn line 74 76 77 

chrome\app\chrome_exe.vsprops line 15 

chrome/app/theme/chromium/BRANDING line 3 4     

chrome/common/chrome_constants.cc line 18 47 49 69 71 

chrome/common/chrome_paths_mac.mm line 62 

chrome/install_static/chromium_install_modes.cc line 19 

chrome/installer/mini_installer/BUILD.gn line 123 

chrome/installer/mini_installer/chrome.release line 9 

chrome/installer/util/util_constants.cc line 209
```